# Cakephp 1.3 Import method

Tags: cakephp-1.3

hey i am new in cake php. I want to use one model in another model then we can user $uses method. this method is very easy. we can also do the same thing with App::import('Controller', 'Users');  ? if yes then tell me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but not with the `$uses` property as the Model doesn't have one.

Take a look at this definition of `$uses`:
*An array containing the class names of models this **controller** uses.*

So what this means is that `$uses` is a Controller property, not a Model one.

Now using one model's functionality in another is possible of course. That is what [Model Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) are for. For example if you have the following:
**Recipe belongsTo User** and the opposite association (for e.g.): **User hasMany Recipe** (A user can have multiple recipes.) from both of these models you would be able to call the other's methods with:
From the User model: `$this->Recipe->find('all');` will do a find on the recipes table. Any custom methods defined in the other model can also be called.

If two models do not have a association defined you can do *"on the fly" binding*. You can read all about these capabilities in the CakePHP Book - [1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/876/The-Manual) or [2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

And a friendly advice - I see you posting this question with the cakephp1.3 tag, If you are new I would strongly recommend starting to learn CakePHP 2.x because this version: 
1. is the newest
2. has the most "object approach"
3. is the one that will be developed even more (not that 1.3 is not being maintained or anything)